# pyqt5 textedit delete lines as they move past specified line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I'd like to setup the PYQT Qtextedit widget and use it to monitor another applications activity log(like tail -f on Linux). Long term I worry about it running for too long and using a lot of ram with the text that builds up. Is it possible to set a limit so that text moving past line x gets deleted? From what I've found it seems to require custom work and I'd like to find a limiter setting if one exists.

Comment: Can you should what you've tried?

Comment: What you want is to set a maximum number of lines in QTextEdit, and if there is a new line you must delete the first ones that were written, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes that is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Im new to pyqt and this i my first approach to the text editor. I've been doing research before I start learning about it and I wasn't finding a way to do what I wanted so I thought i'd ask. If I should be using a different widget i'd like to find out before going through test with the qtextedit widget. I'll learn all about the text editor but for my current project I want to make sure im using the right tools.

Comment: If you use QPlainTextEdit I can give you a simple option, would it be okay if I propose that solution?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, im open to other options. I MAY want to give color to text down the road so i'd prefer font customization if possible. If not i'll deal with it.

Comment: @sidnical, you can easily use a QStyledItemDelegate with a QTextDocument if you need to provide font customization down the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QPlainTextEdit` is an advanced viewer/editor supporting plain text. It is optimized to handle large documents and to respond quickly to user input.

To limit the number of visible lines you must use `setMaximumBlockCount`, in the following example I show the use:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

counter = 0

def addText():
    global counter
    w.appendHtml("<font size=\"3\" color=\"red\">{}</font>".format(counter))
    counter += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QPlainTextEdit()

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(addText)
    timer.start(1000)
    w.setMaximumBlockCount(4)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to use fonts you can do it easily using HTML.